# what is the default Password Policy in mysql 5.0?

Tags: mysql5

what is the default Password Policy in mysql 5.0 ?

Answer (score 1):

if by default password policy you mean "are there a minimum set of rules that need to be met in order to have a valid password with a default installation of MySQL", then the short answer is that there is no default password policy.

a default install of MySQL can be done with no password for a root user at all. Some distros (e.g. debian installing mysql via apt) insist on a root password, but no complexity rules are enforced.

there are 3rd party plugins to create policies (e.g. [securich](http://www.securich.com/)), but nothing that would enforce specific complexity or aging rules within the base system

Answer (score 0):

```
 shell$ mysql
 mysql> use mysql;
 mysql> SELECT Host, User, Password  FROM user;
 +---------------+------+----------+
 | Host          | User | Password |
 +---------------+------+----------+
 | localhost     | root |          |
 | your uname -n | root |          |
 | 127.0.0.1     | root |          |
 | localhost     |      |          |
 | your uname -n |      |          |
 +---------------+------+----------+

 as you can see is quite clear that there is no password but it was said that some linux distribution will 'force' you to have a root password
 use mysqladmin to update the passwords
```

Answer (score 0):

The distros that do force a root password only enforce it at install time. There's nothing stopping root from going in afterwards to do SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('');